# How to specify chisel’s post-processor?

Tags: chisel

Quote from libcores wiki

> One post-processor generates a Verilog that is tuned for FPGA execution. A second generates Verilog that is tuned for ASIC.

Is this true? How to specify which post-processor to use?

I noticed that we can send an option ‘-X xxx’ to chisel, in which ‘xxx’ can be high, middle, low, verilog... Is this related? What’s the exact meaning of these ‘compilers’?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully familiar with the librecores flow, but glancing over https://github.com/librecores/riscv-sodor I don't see any post-processing scripts. It might be worth filing an issue on the repo to ask for clarification on that point.

For Chisel designs in general, people use transforms on the IR to specialize the code for FPGA vs. ASIC. The most common one is with handling memory structures. The behavioral memories emitted by default work well for FPGAs as they are correctly inferred as BRAMs. For ASICs, there is a standard transform to replace memories with blackboxed interfaces such that the user can provide implementations that use SRAM macros from their given implementation technology.

Answer (score 2):

Very narrowly addressing your latter question, the `-X/--compiler` command line argument determines which FIRRTL compiler and emitter to use.

The Chisel3 compiler generates CHIRRTL (a high level form of the FIRRTL intermediate representation). The FIRRTL intermediate representation (IR), described in more detail in a [UC Berkeley Technical Report](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2016/EECS-2016-9.html), is a simple language for describing a circuit.

The FIRRTL compiler, broadly, is moving a circuit, represented in the FIRRTL IR, from a high-level representation (what is described in the specification) to a mid-level representation, and finally to a low-level representation that will easily map to Verilog. The FIRRTL compiler can elect to stop early at High FIRRTL, Mid FIRRTL, or Low FIRRTL or going all the way to Verilog. That `-X/--compiler` argument is telling it if you want to exit early and only target one of these representations.

**Note**: CHIRRTL will eventually be removed and High FIRRTL will be emitted directly by the Chisel compiler.